# Is there a way for multiple users on different machines to write form input to the same Excel file on SharePoint from a C# WinForm program?

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint

I am writing a C# program that gathers statistics on workflow at various workstations. The form has a mix of combo boxes, text boxes, radio buttons, etc. whose values all need to be written chronologically at the click of a Submit button to the same Excel file in SharePoint, likely by multiple users on different workstations. Is there a way to do this?

I've done some research into how to write to an Excel file and a list on SharePoint, but haven't found anything that shows how add to an existing Excel file on SharePoint. All of the users have their own work email used to log into various services, such as the SharePoint site, but an account can be made specifically for the program if permissions will be an issue.

Comment: Could you use a SharePoint form, like [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Forms-Blog/Forms-for-Excel-new-experience-for-Excel-survey-in-Office-365/ba-p/109195) instead of creating a separate app? While I'm sure it's doable, most of the suggestions I've found don't recommend using a shared Excel file as a writable data source within your own application.

Comment: Unfortunately, a form like that wouldn't work. We need the program to be able to run on startup/login and be something that can have most of the fields stay filled in so we can just click "Submit" if we get a lot of patrons in a short period of time without having to spend extra time filling everything in again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible if all the users have edit access to the file and you are using SharePoint managed csom or rest apis for that.

Comment: Can you suggest a good resource that might help me out with that? I haven't coded with SharePoint at all before, so the whole concept is pretty new to me.

Comment: see this for plain text file: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/213929/write-text-to-a-text-file-in-sharepoint-library-using-csom
for excel you might use OpenXml sdk

Comment: One problem comes in if two or more users submit forms at the same time. It might fail when they both try to write. Worse, both users load the file and both append their record, then both save successfully, and one overwrites the other. That's why I'd lean towards a database. It's meant to handle concurrent writes.

Comment: you can use check out and check in option using code as well and dis allowing users to edit while check out

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer! This gives me a good starting point!